# When to use the ています form

Tags: grammar

I know you usually use ています to describe things that are ongoing.But do you also use the ています form to say things like: "School starts at 6 o'clock every day" or "School usually ends at 3pm" since it’s something that happens everyday and therefore is ongoing?

Comment: Also, if I wanted to say something like: "Why does the night end?" Do I still use ています since it’s something that literally happens every day?

Answer (score 1):

It is a little too broad a question to give an answer, but let me just give some ideas specific to starting/ending.

Roughly, when the verb is instantaneous ています sounds "have happened" rather than ongoing or habitual.

---

- 学校は毎日9時に始まります *School starts at 9 o'clock every day.* (btw isn't 6 o'clock too early?)

始まっています means "has started". So used in a sentence like

- 学校はもう始まっています *School has already started (say, now it's 10 o'clock).*

Same for finishing.

- 授業は3時に終わります *Class ends at three.*
- 授業はもう終わっています *Class is already finished.*

For sunrise, it can be ongoing as a process. So

- 日がのぼっています

is, strictly speaking, ambiguous between *The sun has risen already* and *The sun is rising (now)*, but I think it is more like to mean 1.

---

For other non-instantaneous verbs, ています may mean it is habitual or ongoing.

- 最近村上春樹を読んでいます *These days I read Haruki Murakami('s works)*. It is possible to say 最近村上春樹をよみます.
- 今、村上春樹を読んでいます *I'm reding Haruki Murakami.* 今、村上春樹を読みます would mean (a bit unnatural but) *I'm going to read Haruki Murakami now*.

Comment: Yeah I wrote 6 o'clock on accident, but thank you so much for your answer!